# error while mocking in angular jasmine test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am getting an error while running the following angular test while using jasmine and karma. I have mocked the service dependencies 
of the component. However there is function of the tradeservice that is being used in the component. I have tried mocking the 
function but it still complains

```
TypeError: this.tradeService.getCurrencyCodes is not a function
```

What is the problem ?

In the component code

```
constructor(private tradeService: TradeService,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private orderService: OrderService,
        private valueDateService: ValueDateService,
        private dateService: DateService,
        private clientService: ClientService) {
    }

 ngOnInit() {
        this.getCurrencyCodes();
    }


  private getCurrencyCodes() {
        this.tradeService.getCurrencyCodes()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.currencyList = data;
            },
            error => {
                this.messageViewerModel.messages.push("Unable to get Currency codes");
            });
    }
```

In the spec file of the component

```
 class MockDateService {

}


class MockTradeService {
    getCurrencyCodes() {
        return;
    }
}

class MockAuthService {

}

class MockOrderService {

}

class MockValueDateService {

}

class MockClientService {

}


class MockMessageViewerModel {
    title: string;
    messages: string[];
   }

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-message-viewer',
    template: ''
  })
  class MockMessageViewerComponent {
    @Input()
    messageViewer: MockMessageViewerModel;    
  }

describe('StripOrderComponent', () => {
    let component: StripOrderComponent;
    let clientService: ClientService;
    let tradeService: TradeService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<StripOrderComponent>;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                FormsModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useClass: TranslateLanguageLoader
                    }
                })
            ],
            declarations: [
                StripOrderComponent,
                MockMessageViewerComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
                [{ provide: DateService, useValue: MockDateService }],
                [{ provide: TradeService, useValue: MockTradeService }],
                [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: MockAuthService }],
                [{ provide: OrderService, useValue: MockOrderService }],
                [{ provide: ValueDateService, useValue: MockValueDateService }],
                [{ provide: ClientService, useValue: MockClientService }]
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StripOrderComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();


    });

    it('should be created', () => {

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });


});
```

TradeService

```
getCurrencyCodes() {
        return this.tradeEndpoint.getCurrencyCodesEndpoint<string[]>();
    }
```

Comment: Do you need these lines at the top of your test or can they be omitted? `let clientService: ClientService;
    let tradeService: TradeService;`

Comment: can be ommitted

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `useValue` into `useClass` in following line.

```
[{ provide: TradeService, useValue: MockTradeService }],
```

Answer (score 0):

try to delete **fixture.detectChanges** inside your **beforeEach**, it's probably the cause why your test fails, **detectChanges** will only work for **onPush** events

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StripOrderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // delete this
})
```